# Setting a PrintJob name

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Is it possible to set the name for a [PrintJob](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/printing/PrintJob.html) when printing a MovieClip? At the moment the PrintJob is just called "Flash" and when i try to save it as a PDF it is named "Flash.pdf".

Comment: If you scroll down your link, you should notice PrintJob class property jobName. It's only available in AIR.

Comment: Yes, thats the problem - i want to assign a jobName in a Flash Application.